# Deselect column from IQueryable linq entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression, iqueryable

I'm working with entity framework code first against an Oracle database. Several of our entities have byte arrays (blobs) in them. Sometimes I want the blob and sometimes I don't.  I would like to have a simple clean way of taking an `IQueryable<T>` and deselecting the blob column while keeping it strongly typed as `IQueryable<T>`.

Given an `IQueryable<T>` I would like to deselect a specified property. I'm dreaming of an extension method with a signature similar to the following:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Deselect<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, PropertyInfo deselectedProperty)
{
    // re-project the queryable without the specified property
}

public static IQueryable<T> Deselect<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> selector)
{
    // re-project the queryable without property specified in selector
}
```

Is this possible?  I'm thinking some sort of expression visitor to find the most recent projection of the data, copy that and re-project the data without the specified property/column. I tried hardcoding the projection to the same type but entity framework threw an exception saying I couldn't call constructors for mapped types and I'd really like to be able to maintain my return type if possible. I know I can perform the deselect by selecting into a new anonymous type without the property, but then I'm unable to return my entity type unless I force evaluation of the queryable.

The desired usage would be as follows:

```
interface IHaveBlob 
{ 
    byte[] Blob { get; set; }
}

class ComplexType : IHaveBlob
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public byte[] Blob { get; set; }
}

public void DeselectBlob<T>(IQueryable<T> source) where T : IHaveBlob
{
    return source.Deselect(x => x.Blob);
}
```

Comment: Are you working with Code First?

Comment: Yes, I am working with Code First

Comment: You should change the way your going about this in my opinion. Blob should really be a POCO class object, and rather than have an Interface against you ComplexType, have a Blob as a Navigational property in its property set. As you mentioned, sometimes you dont need a Blob, with EF you can take advantage of lazy loading, so infact the Blob object is only ever loaded when you chose to access it. Otherwise, it isnt ever loaded into memory.

Comment: I agree many things should be changed, however, the change you propose is not a trivial one to make in the code base. The entities are all POCOs wired up using Code First, but my desired solution is much more general than EF... I'd prefer a solution that involves rewriting the expression tree to perform the select as I want it to.

Comment: Also, If I make the blob have its own mapping then it would remove it from the entity that represents the table since you can't map the same  column to multiple entities

Comment: But you can map two entities having one-to-one relations to the same table and that is exactly recommended solution for this type of issues. The master entity will contain everything except the blob and the dependent entity will contain primary key (also working as FK to master) and the blob.

Comment: And this requires a database change or can EF do this all via code first mappings?

Comment: See [Table Splitting](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/04/24/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-4-table-splitting.aspx).